# Ubuntu on Lenovo Flex 5 Ideapad 14are05 won't recognize touch pad

Tags: kernel, mouse, touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

This issue has appeared a lot and I've tried almost every fix from modifying the grub file to patching the kernel to uninstalling certain drivers. None of them have worked. I started with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and have since updated the kernel to 6.2 and Ubuntu to 22.10 to no avail. I also tried installing libinput and evdev drivers.

xinput, libinput, lshw, and hwinfo show no sign of a touch pad, msft or elan. I've tried damn near everything and can't find any trace of it. The touch pad works perfectly fine on Windows, so it's not a hardware issue.

I even tried Fedora and Manjaro, but the touch pad didn't work on their live boots either. The touchscreen, keyboard, and everything else work fine, it is just the touch pad.

If Ubuntu is just a lost cause for this laptop, I would be open to any other distros that are compatible.

Comment: can you give `sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi` a try?