# Trackpad not working on Ideapad Flex 5 - Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

I recently purchased a [Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-flex-series/ideapad-flex-5-gen-8-(16-inch-amd)/82xy002kus). I instantly removed Windows 11 Home and installed Ubuntu 23.04. Only problem: the trackpad isn't working. **Ubuntu doesn't even recognize the trackpad**, as you can see from the `lsusb` output below:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c7a:0576 LighTuning Technology Inc. EgisTec EH576
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 30c9:0053 Luxvisions Innotech Limited Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've tried other linux distros; same problem. The trackpad works fine in the BIOS menu however, so I know it's not a hardware issue. I've looked everywhere online and I can't find anything.

#### Edit

This question [is a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475440/ubuntu-on-lenovo-flex-5-ideapad-14are05-wont-recognize-touch-pad) but with no answer. Someone please help me, I really need this to work.

Output of `libinput list-devices`:

```
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
Group:            1
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Power Button
Kernel:           /dev/input/event0
Group:            2
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Lid Switch
Kernel:           /dev/input/event1
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     switch
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           PixArt USB Optical Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event4
Group:            4
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Integrated Camera: Integrated C
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           Ideapad extra buttons
Kernel:           /dev/input/event5
Group:            6
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event2
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

I ran `sudo dmesg | grep modprobe` after running `sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi` and got this:

```
[    2.261372] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice - Slice /system/modprobe.
[    2.273890] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs...
[    2.274501] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
[    2.275151] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
[    2.275783] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@fuse.service - Load Kernel Module fuse...
[    2.280092] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.280232] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs.
[    2.280437] systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.280591] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
[    2.280779] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.280932] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@fuse.service - Load Kernel Module fuse.
[    2.293895] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.294095] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
[    3.880063] audit: type=1400 audit(1691009312.052:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=665 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    3.880067] audit: type=1400 audit(1691009312.052:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=665 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: can you give `sudo modprobe i2c-hid-acpi` a try?

Comment: I did, nothing happened

Comment: Can you post the output of `libinput list-devices`?

Comment: Should be above. I had to use `sudo` because of permissions

Comment: Was that run after you've executed the `modprobe` command? Do you see any log messages from `dmesg` when you run the `modprobe` command?

Comment: Yes, `libinput list-devices` was run after I executed the `modprobe`. The output of the dmesg is above

Comment: this looks like what others are experiencing in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1878279

Answer (score 0):

For the Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 14ARE05, no known workaround, but I would try to add to the kernel cmdline "i8042.reset=1" per the description in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.8/+bug/1912880 that forced shutdown while suspend get the touchpad back (though I use such i8042 reset on my Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S1 to fix the opposite ie no keyboard/touchpad after a force shutdown while suspended, it is worth a try. I have used this hack since it was reported ).

You might also want to try "i8042.nopnp=1" as the dmesg log from the above report tells:

```
 [ 0.602905] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
```

You could also try `i8042.nomux=1` then  `i8042.kbreset=1`

You might also want to report the bug to the Linux kernel ML or bugzilla https://bugzilla.kernel.org/.
You might want to post your dmesg output or at least:
`sudo dmesg|grep -E "PS\/2|ACPI|hid|i8042"`

For the Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15are05, [IdeaPad 5 15are05 - elan touchpad not working on 20.04 nor on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248176/ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04/1257523#1257523)

> modprobe i2c_hid
> echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/elants_i2c/unbind
> echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/i2c_hid/bind
> or add `initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c_driver_init` to your kernel cmdline (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" in /etc/default/grub
> (2020 might be fixed upstream)

For the Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14IIL05, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe/+bug/1880172/comments/53, that is:

> adding the following arguments to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT.
>
> "i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
> (2020)

@SO_32 you might want to try without `pci=nocrs`. i8042 parameters ought not to affect wifi devices on its own.

Comment: Hello, not only this didn't work for me, it also disabled my wifi